# lm(formula) in R behaves differently within parLapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply, lm

First I create a pair of example dataframes:

```
df = data.frame("sample1" = runif(10), "sample2" = runif(10), "sample3" = runif(10), "sample4" = runif(10))
traits = data.frame("var1" = c(rep("group1", 2), rep("group2", 2)))
rownames(traits) = colnames(df)
```

If I create a formula as a text string, I can plug it right into lm()

```
> row = t(df[1,])
> ModString = "row ~ traits$var1"
> Mod = lm(as.formula(ModString))
> Mod

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(ModString))

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)  traits$var1group2  
           0.7799             0.1788
```

But if I try to do the same thing with parLapply, I get an error indicating that the "traits" argument was not working as expected:

```
> num_cores <- detectCores() - 1
> cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
> results <- parLapply(cl = cl, seq(1:10), function(i, df, traits){
+     row = df[i,]
+     ModString = "vector ~ traits$factor1"
+     Mod = lm(ModString)
+     return(Mod)
+ }, df = df, traits = traits)
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  9 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'traits' not found
```

But what is strange is that the "traits" argument IS making it into the parLapply as I am using, it seems to be something about the way lm() works that is the problem. I can input and return "traits" just fine:

```
> cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
> results <- parLapply(cl = cl, seq(1:10), function(i, df, traits){
+     row = df[i,]
+     traits2 = traits
+     ModString = "vector ~ traits$factor1"
+     return(list(traits2, row, ModString))
+ }, df = df, traits = traits)
> results
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
          var1
sample1 group1
sample2 group1
sample3 group2
sample4 group2

[[1]][[2]]
    sample1   sample2   sample3  sample4
1 0.6941108 0.8656177 0.9807334 0.936609

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "vector ~ traits$factor1"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
          var1
sample1 group1
sample2 group1
sample3 group2
sample4 group2

[[2]][[2]]
    sample1   sample2   sample3   sample4
2 0.1007983 0.5599374 0.0208095 0.8082196

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "vector ~ traits$factor1"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
          var1
sample1 group1
sample2 group1
sample3 group2
sample4 group2

[[3]][[2]]
    sample1   sample2  sample3   sample4
3 0.9633059 0.7564143 0.913617 0.4179525

[[3]][[3]]
[1] "vector ~ traits$factor1"


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
          var1
sample1 group1
sample2 group1
sample3 group2
sample4 group2

[[4]][[2]]
     sample1  sample2  sample3   sample4
4 0.06625104 0.390351 0.511572 0.8386714

[[4]][[3]]
[1] "vector ~ traits$factor1"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
          var1
sample1 group1
sample2 group1
sample3 group2
sample4 group2

[[5]][[2]]
    sample1   sample2    sample3  sample4
5 0.6135228 0.4926991 0.08513074 0.105647

[[5]][[3]]
[1] "vector ~ traits$factor1"


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
          var1
sample1 group1
sample2 group1
sample3 group2
sample4 group2

[[6]][[2]]
    sample1   sample2   sample3   sample4
6 0.7121677 0.6554129 0.6409468 0.4906039

[[6]][[3]]
[1] "vector ~ traits$factor1"


[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
          var1
sample1 group1
sample2 group1
sample3 group2
sample4 group2

[[7]][[2]]
    sample1  sample2   sample3   sample4
7 0.4651641 0.546514 0.4039608 0.1758802

[[7]][[3]]
[1] "vector ~ traits$factor1"


[[8]]
[[8]][[1]]
          var1
sample1 group1
sample2 group1
sample3 group2
sample4 group2

[[8]][[2]]
    sample1   sample2   sample3   sample4
8 0.5121237 0.4950444 0.9662431 0.6851582

[[8]][[3]]
[1] "vector ~ traits$factor1"


[[9]]
[[9]][[1]]
          var1
sample1 group1
sample2 group1
sample3 group2
sample4 group2

[[9]][[2]]
    sample1  sample2   sample3   sample4
9 0.2486208 0.135422 0.2128657 0.7332921

[[9]][[3]]
[1] "vector ~ traits$factor1"


[[10]]
[[10]][[1]]
          var1
sample1 group1
sample2 group1
sample3 group2
sample4 group2

[[10]][[2]]
      sample1   sample2   sample3   sample4
10 0.06203028 0.7916495 0.3528376 0.2259685

[[10]][[3]]
[1] "vector ~ traits$factor1"
```

What embarrassingly trivial detail am I missing here?

Comment: I have very little experience with `parLapply`, but I *can* tell you that you should not be building formulas with `$` at all. The formula should contain the variable names of columns in the `data` argument. e.g. `lm(var1 ~ var2 + var3,data = my_data)` where `var1`, etc are all columns in `my_data`.

Comment: same thing happens if I index by name

Comment: Yeah, the problem is with your fundamental approach and the whole way that your data is organized. Minor tweaks while still holding the data in two different data frame one of which has columns as rows is just going to be so complicated to manage that you're going to run into lots of problems.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not avoidable in my situation, this was just the simplest example I could make.

Comment: It's totally doable, and much cleaner...I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way; note the radically different data organization:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(parallel)

#You seem to have rows of data that should be columns,
# this puts things in a form more suitable for work in R
df_new <- df %>% 
    mutate(row = 1:n()) %>% 
    gather(key = sample,value = val,sample1:sample4) %>% 
    arrange(row,sample)

#Data in rownames is not terribly useful
traits_new <- rownames_to_column(traits,"sample")

#Now we can put it all in *one* data frame
df_new <- left_join(df_new,
                    traits_new,
                    by = "sample")

#...and split it into a list representing each of the df's you
# want a lm() fit on
df_new_split <- split(df_new,df_new$row)

#Wrapper for lm with the only formula we need
fit_lm <- function(x){
    lm(val ~ var1,data = x)
}

num_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)

results <- parLapply(cl = cl,df_new_split,fit_lm)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really need the data to be organized this way because of what I do with it downstream. My real question is why the string is interpreted differently in the two contexts.

Comment: @Thoughtcraft The reason is bc lm() isn't meant to be used in the way you are. The ability to pass variable names in formulae that are looked up in the calling environment (how the first attempt works) is meant for simple, interactive work, not programming. All the data transformations I show can be undone later.

Comment: Sure, but then why does lm work with the same string and data outside parLapply? This is what I want to figure out.

Comment: @Thoughtcraft Because when you aren't splitting things into multiple processes, R has a system for looking up name in successive environments. Even then, things could go very wrong if you're doing it inside nested functions. But using `parLapply` I would have zero assumptions about what each process can access from your global environment.

Comment: @Thoughtcraft Here, maybe this will be clearer: when `lm` looks for `traits` when you call `parLapply` it would normally look first in whatever you gave the `data` argument. That's the normal way to do things. Since you didn't provide that, it will next look in the calling environment; but it won't see the `traits` you passed as a function argument. That just exists as a promise object, and each process probably starts with a clean environment, so anything you created in your global environment is inaccessible.

Comment: I'm not sure I do understand. I thought the purpose of the `...` argument(s) was to pass those arguments as arguments to the function being run in parLappy. And why is the `traits` argument accessible to the assignment operator in `traits2 = traits`, but not to lm()? Shouldn't `=` and `lm` have access to the same scope?

Comment: @Thoughtcraft Having access to, and knowing to look there are two different things. When you make an assignment like `traits2 <- traits`, R has a process for looking for `traits` that includes checking argument to the function you're inside. But remember that once you call `lm()` you've descended a whole layer of scope. Everything that happens there is in _another_ whole new environment. And the way lm works is that it checks the `data` argument, and then it checks the calling environment; merely passing an argument doesn't create the actual argument in that environment.

Comment: Wow, I feel silly now, my example is totally messed up.. I failed to use `as.formula` in my `parLapply`, and also forgot to change variable name `vector` to `row` and to transpose it. How did I not see that?? Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score -1):

OK I feel really silly but I'm going to leave the question up because it's a great example of how easy it is to get confused when copy-pasting and editing multiple versions of code. I did not consistently use `as.formula` in my `parLapply`, and also forgot to change variable name vector to row and to transpose it.

So. The following works just dandy:

```
require(parallel)
num_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
results <- parLapply(cl = cl, seq(1:10), function(i, df, traits){
    row = t(df[i,])
    ModString = "row ~ traits[,\"var1\"]"
    Mod = lm(as.formula(ModString))
    return(Mod)
}, df = df, traits = traits)
```

Comment: Don't get why this answer is not useful. It is the cause of my problem. Although I won't argue with anyone who downvotes the question, as it was rather poorly considered.